# in a mass spectrometer why do the ions inside the acceleration chamber not interact with each other and disturb the reading

Tags: mass-spectrometry

This would be in both time of flight and deflection mass spectrometers, and this would be when you are trying to find the relative abundance of isotopes of an element.

Comment: There is high enough vacuum for ions to be far enough apart for mutual force negligible to external EM force.

Comment: There is a force from the other ions $\sum_{i \ne j} e_ie_j/r_{i,j}^2 $ and one from the accelerating electric field also $e_jE_0$. Combined these limit the resolution. The force between ions can be limited by the ionising conditions used.

Comment: Space charge effects are well known, as are conditions and techniques to minimize the effect on the data. Lots of papers out their to dig into details.